# Wipi monitor mode?

Tags: raspbian

I have a raspberry pi model and as a wifi card/adapter I use the wipi. It works fine and all is good. Apart from I was wondering is it possible to set it to monitor mode? And if you can't with the wipi. What other raspberry pi dongles can go into monitor mode.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `WiPi` should support monitor mode.
`iw list` will show capabilities.

PS You need to install the `iw` package.

Comment: Would I just do sudo apt-get install iw list? Is there a way to install it from the terminal? I also did try to put it into monitor mode but it said not supported, I may have done it wrong though

Comment: `sudo apt-get install iw` `list` is an `iw` command. I have never used monitor mode on the Pi. You may need to set monitor in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: When I do /etc/network/interfaces it says permission denied

Comment: @Millways I did iw list and it said that whatever it listed has monitor mode I think...

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` is owned by root, so you need `sudo`

Comment: I'm sure I did that and it said command not found

Comment: And also how would I actually set it to monitor mode?

Comment: As I said I have never used monitor mode on the Pi. I presume you are using something like wireshark, so you should look at the appropriate website. You may need to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` (using your preferred editor), but you may be able to activate monitor mode from the software you are using; this depends on the kernel support, but many Linux implementations permit this.

Comment: Ok so I am editing  /etc/network/interfaces but how would I set monitor mode. Sorry for all the questions but I am a noob when it comes to linux

Comment: whenever I try to set it to monitor mode after setting it down it says it is busy

Comment: give this a try: sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode Monitor
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the WiPi does support monitor mode. I tested it using: `iw list` as per the answer above and part of the output confirmed this:

```
software interface modes (can always be added):
     * AP/VLAN
     * monitor
```

I tested it by switching the WiPi to monitor mode with:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down

sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor

sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Then running `iwconfig` to confirms that the WiPi is in monitor mode:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
lo        no wireless extensions.
```